# Spring: как получить в Java-классе информацию о WildFly?

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

Возникла необходимость получить в Java-классе информацию об инстансе WildFly, на котором развернуто приложение (в идеале - имя сервера, либо любую другую информацию, по которой можно было бы опознать этот WF). Существуют ли способы получить такую информацию? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `System.getProperty("jboss.server.name")`.

[Что еще можно получить](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/WildFly_System_Properties)